# How to convert string back and forth to binary

Tags: php, string, binary

I need to be able to turn a string into its binary parts. Say I have the string:

```
"R!Testing"
```

I want a function to return the respective binary:

```
"010100100010000101010100011001010111001101110100011010010110111001100111"
```

and also have another function to also turn that binary in the string `"R!Testing"` for example. Currently I am using the following.

```
function messageToBinary($message) {
    $value = unpack('H*', $message);
    return base_convert($value[1], 16, 2);
}
// Turn string of bits into its text equivalent
function binaryToMessage($binary) {
    return pack('H*', base_convert($binary, 2, 16));
}
```

This of course has several issues I believe. Some characters fail (I think because 16 is the max?) to convert properly and also base_convert sometimes fails with large strings due to overflow issues.

What is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in a loop instead of trying to treat the whole thing as one big number. `ord()` returns the character code of a character, and `sprintf()` can be used to convert that to a fixed-length binary number.

```
function messageToBinary($message) {
    $len = strlen($message);
    $result = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {

        $result .= sprintf("%08b", ord($message[$i]));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

To go the other way, extract 8-bit segments of the string, convert them from binary to decimal, then use `chr()` to convert that to a character.

```
function binaryToMessage($binary) {
    $len = strlen($binary);
    $result = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += 8) {
        $n = substr($binary, $i, 8);
        $result .= chr(bindec($n));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Note that this only works for 8-bit characters. For Unicode, you'll need to get more complex.

Comment: Ah okay, let me implement that.

Comment: on the way back should I try to get the character code from the binary number and turn that into a string?

Comment: I've added the reverse function

Comment: Ah I see with the binary to decimal. Thanks for the help!